# Spring Boot No me ejecuta un Controller cuando lo coloco en un package diferente

Tags: spring-boot

Buenas tardes desarrolladores, estoy iniciando en el mundo de Spring Boot, me generé un Spring  sencillo llamado AppSqlServerApplication con el Spring Initializr (https://start.spring.io/), La cuestion es que quiero ordenar la aplicaciòn por paquetes com.example.AppSqlServer , controllers, y entities.
Dentro del paquete com.example.AppSqlServer se encuentra la clase principal que arranca la aplicación;El problema es que cuando creo una clase UserController dentro del paquete controllers no se me ejecuta, pero si paso dicha clase ("UserController") al paquete com.example.AppSqlServer donde esta la clase principal si se me ejecuta. ¿Alguien me puede decir como soluciono esto?
Gracias...
Esta es la estructura de archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
package controllers;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class UserController {

 public UserController() {

 }

 @GetMapping(value = "/homeUser")
 public String HomeUser() {
    return "Hello User";
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que crear tu estructura de paquetes a partir del paquete donde tienes la clase principal de Spring (`AppSqlServerApplication`).
Es decir, `com.example.AppSqlServer.controllers` y `com.example.AppSqlServer.entities`.

Otra opción es, en AppSqlServerApplication, anotar de la siguiente manera los paquetes que quieras incluir:

```
@ComponentScan({"controllers","entities"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppSqlServerApplication {
...
```

Personalmente, prefiero la primera, menos código y más fácil de mantener.